# Как с помощью css сделать широкую цифру с цветовым градиентом?

Tags: css, css3, svg

Как с помощью css сделать широкую цифру с цветовым градиентом, как изображенно на картинке?

[image: Как с помощью css сделать широкую цифру с цветовым градиентом, как изображенно на картинке?]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только шрифт поменить

```css
body{
  font-family:Helvetica,serif;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="200">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="80%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:green;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:lightgreen;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <text x="0" y="75" font-size="100" font-weight="900" fill="url(#grad)">1</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

Если используется `svg`. то наиболее простым способом является команда масштабирования `scale(X Y)`

Увеличение ширины цифры на 30% - scale(1.3 1)
Увеличение на 50% -  scale(1.5 1)

```css
<style>
body{
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

```html
<svg height="300" width="300">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#9BF1B6;" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#B4F89A;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <text transform="scale(1 1)" x="0" y="75" font-size="100" font-weight="900" fill="url(#grad)">1</text>
  <text transform="translate(-5 0) scale(1.3 1)" x="0" y="150" font-size="100" font-weight="900" fill="url(#grad)">1</text> 
   <text transform="translate(-15 0) scale(1.5 1)" x="0" y="225" font-size="100" font-weight="900" fill="url(#grad)">1</text>
  </svg>
```

*Адаптивный вариант со стилями в `CSS` Работает во всех браузерах:*

```css
svg text{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:100px;
  font-weight:900px;
  fill:url(#grad);
}
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#B4F89A;" /> #B4F89A
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#B4389A;" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <text transform="scale(1 1)" x="0" y="75" >1</text>
  <text transform="translate(-18 0) scale(1.5 1)" x="0" y="150">1</text> 
   <text transform="translate(-36 0) scale(2 1)" x="0" y="225">1</text>
  </svg>
```